# Increase/Decrease x and z indexes of line renderer based on a gameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to increase/decrease the x and z indexes of set positions of line renderer based on another gameObject's position. Such that if the gameObject moves forward/backward, the x axis of line renderer is effected and similar to z axis if it moves left/right.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent (typeof (LineRenderer))]
public class LineRenderer_Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    private LineRenderer line;
    public bool DrawLine = false;
    public GameObject Follow_Obj;
    float posx;
    float posz;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start () {
       
        line = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();

        line.SetPosition(0, new Vector3(0,0,0));
        DrawLine = true;
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (DrawLine == true) {
            //Calculate if Follow_Obj is moving forward/backward/left/right
            posx += 0.1f*Time.deltaTime;//Forward
            posx -= 0.1f*Time.deltaTime;//Backward
            posz += 0.1f*Time.deltaTime;//Right
            posz -= 0.1f*Time.deltaTime;//left
            line.SetPosition(1, new Vector3(posx,0,posz));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to know in which direction an object is moving simply keep track of its last position and compare them:

```
[SerializeField] private float length = 0.5f;
private Vector3 lastPos;

void Update () 
{
    if (DrawLine) 
    {
        var delta = Follow_Obj.transform.position - lastPos;
        var direction = delta.normalized;

        line.SetPosition(0, Follow_Obj.transform.position);
        line.SetPosition(1, Follow_Obj.transform.position - direction * length));
    }

    lastPos = Follow_Obj.transform.position;
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply. Do you know why I am getting an error for Vector3(direction * length)?  ```Vector3 does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments```

Comment: I know why, because it is wrong ^^ Just was a typo (I'm on smartphone), updated the code

Comment: Thank you. But it is not exactly how I wanted. You see my logic is to make the line start from the the Follow_Obj's position and keep following it. The index (1) should be affected. So this is what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Well you make the position `0` at `0,0,0` so it will never start at the objects position .. so again what exactly is the line supposed to do? Does my code update help you? ;)